# SARIMAX coefficient for exogenous variable interpretation

Tags: arima, interpretation

I have a SARIMAX model with exogenous variables and need to interpret the coefficients before exog variables.  The result of the model is below. So for example I want to interpret a coefficient 48.1902 before "tv3" variable - can I say that tv3 increased by 1 results in 48.1902 increase in my dependent variable? Or as it's not a simple linear regression, I have to do this in some more complex way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to Interpret ARIMA Results - Analyzing Alpha Interpreting ARMA model results in Statsmodels for absolute beginners | by Nikol Holicka | Analytics Vidhya | Medium